# wacom axis sensitivity

Tags: xrandr, wacom

My wacom stretchs everything vertically. How do I lower its vertical sensitivity?

I use my display rotated to see it vertically. May be it is confusing the tablet. (But I switched off absolute positioning in system prefs.) Intuous pen *small* is really not big, so I want to use it in its ordinary position, though may be rotating of it could solve particular problem. But I need it to be as wide as it is.

Please, help with configuring.